# Remove Exchange message size limit for a user

Tags: exchange-2007, windows-sbs-2008

A user is trying to send a large email (over 10MB) but Exchange says they cannot do this as the limit (10MB) is being reached. How can I turn off the limit for this user please?

Comment: Silly question perhaps but in light of the investigations below, I've got to ask if you're 100% sure it's the exchange server itself and not another system further up the path that is rejecting the email. My servers would certainly bounce a 10mb email straight back at you with no further discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of Exchange?

In any version, you can set per-user quota limits which override the default global limits and the default mailbox database's limits.

If the message is addressed to an external user, you'll also need to check the limits on outbound messages.

Exchange 2003:
http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Set-Size-Limits-Messages.html

Exchange 2007:
http://www.msexchange.org/articles-tutorials/exchange-server-2007/management-administration/exchange-2007-message-size-limits.html

Comment: I'm running SBS 2008 and Exchange 2007. I read that link and tried the Get-Mailbox cmdlet for the user in-question and it said MaxSend is 50MB, MaxReceive is unlimited. But they still cannot send the email. Does this mean I have to remove the restriction from the server to get it to work

Comment: Yes, if you have a restriction on the send connector for Internet messages, it will apply globally. The user will be able to send large messages to other internal users, but not to external addresses.

Comment: So there's no way to remove the restriction on a per-user basis for external messages?

Comment: I've just removed the limit from the send connector. Tried to re-send my 20MB email to an external contact, and it bounced back again, from my server saying I had exceeded the send limit. There is no limit. Is this a bug in Exchange?

Comment: Something's not right here... Just ran "Set-Transportconfig -maxsendsize 50MB" and tried again. Exchange still says a 20MB email is too big! What's causing this?

Comment: Have you followed all the steps in the page I linked? Also, are you sure the message is not being rejected by the remote host? Can you succesfully send this message between two *internal* users?

Comment: I can send the message to myself. However the message given in the NDR is the same as before, and it says it's being generated by my server, not the remote server.

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Something must *still* be wrong. You'll have to find what...

Answer (score 0):

The message size limits are set system-wide on the Send and Receive Connectors. It can not be set per-user.

Comment: The sbs-2008 may have been a mistag, if your answer was specific to that version.

Comment: The limits on connectors only apply to message going through them, which is not always the case. A limit on a send connector will *not* apply to a message sent between internal users.

Comment: Sorry yes this is related to SBS 2008. This problem is with emails sent to external users. In Exchange there is an option to set the send/receive limit, and although I've changed it to 51200KB (50MB) it still doesn't allow the user to send the email.

Comment: @reado, read my link on Exchange 2007. There are various limits that can influence a user's maximum allowed message size, and if they conflict, the lowest one applies.

Comment: @Kara My apologies it is indeed related to SBS2008. I fixed the post before migrating it, and the revision history did not migrate along.